# Elegant validation techniques for Entity First MVC3 site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, validation

Having never done an MVC site I am about to start a project for a very large one.  I feel confidant enough to do it, but I have one thing I need help figuring out.

We are definitely going to be using an "Entity First" method and have a single .edmx file defining the models, there are multiple reasons for this but just know that this is a definite piece of the puzzle.

So the piece I need to figure out is how to come up with an elegant way to do validations against Entities on a page, without hand coding each page, at least for the majority of things.

Are there any already popular methods for doing some basic validations?  Things like MaxLength or Required or MinDate, etc?

Anything more complex than that and I understand I'd have to code it myself, but this site is going to be very large and I really need to find a way to speed some of the basic tasks up.

**EDIT**
I should point out a couple important facts.
1) Our database already exists and was created by a DBA before developers even came into the picture.
2) There are hundreds of tables and stored procedures already created.
3) When changes will need to be made to the database, they will go through the DBA, who we will not always have instant access too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you use Entity Framework Code First, you don't have a .edxm file storing your models or relationships between them: you just write your POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) classes, and that's it — Code First will figure out the relations between your models based on naming conventions.

---

To validate your (view) models, I recommend using **FluentValidation** or **DataAnnotations**. Both let you define validation rules in one place, either using a fluent validation API in different entity validation classes (FluentValidation) or using attributes to decorate your entity properties (DataAnnotations). The advantage of DataAnnotations over FluentValidation is that you get additional client-side validation out of the box.

Whichever framework you choose, both ship with a bunch of predefined validation rules like *Required*, *Range*, or *MaxLength* (see [Fluent Validation for .NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) or [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) for examples).

Comment: Yes, but I specifically said we would be using a .edmx file.  One major reason is that the database already exists and is massive.  So we can spend weeks creating Code First models or we can generate a single .edmx file and start working.  FluentValidation seems like it might work so I'll look into that.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that you already have an existing database. In that case, you might want to have a look at Scott Guthrie's excellent blog post "Using EF 'Code First' with an Existing Database" (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx). The point about Code First, however, is *not to have a .edxm file*. If you decide to stick with it, you either choose the **Model First** or the **Database First** paradigm; Code First relies on POCOs.

Answer (score 0):

I would 100% absolutely still use some POCO class. Download the DBContext generator template that will then create the code first from your model, OR use the Entity Framework Power Tools to reverse engineer an existing database. The down side to these methods though is that you won't get client side validation, only when saving it will you get the validation. You can however still add your validation attributes if you so choose for client side validation in addition using 
[MetaData Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx) to use Data Annotations on your properties and get client side validation using the built in jQuery unobtrusive validation.

However - what we're talking about here goes against the basic design of MVC good practices anyways. Ideally your views should have ViewModels that are at times only a portion of an entity, in this case your validation attributes are still generated on your properties as DataAnnotations in MetaDataClasses.

If you feel this is all too much work and you are fine with just the server validation and have made a decision not to use ViewModels and rely on the Entity Frameworks validation- or use ViewModels and still rely on EF validation, then you will need a handler like the following in your controller (or other layer that has been given access to ModelState) to catch the following exception. Note I use AutoMapper to copy the properties between my ViewModel to my Entity.

[Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) (right click in your project in solution explorer after its installed and there will be an new 'Entity Framework' menu -> Reverse Engineer - note it doesnt generate [TimeStamp] attributes and forgets to put in schema names - besides that its pretty good)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CustomerCreateViewModel customerViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap();
            Customer customer = Mapper.Map(customerViewModel);

            var repository = new CustomerRepository(db);
            repository.Save(customer);
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id=customer.CustomerId});
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            foreach (var error in ex.EntityValidationErrors.First().ValidationErrors)
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
    return View(customerViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon Galloway has a nice article called [Generating EF Code First model classes from an existing database](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/02/24/generating-ef-code-first-model-classes-from-an-existing-database.aspx) which I think will help you greatly in getting your application up and going from what you described.

Secondly, from having built out our own MVC application so far, I've found that you're really not going to be working directly with Entity Framework models directly very often. Most of the time you'll end up with some type of view model for doing your gets and posts to. Adding DataAnnotations to those class properties will make it very easy for you to do your validations on the client side. Once you have validated the data from the client side and checked your entities against any business rules, you really should then be able to trust the data and use EF to do your basic CRUD work with.

Good luck, and hope this helps you some with your project.

Answer (score 0):

What Marius is trying to tell you is that "Code First" refers to your "model" being defined by fluent code mappings that do not rely on an .edmx file.  Therefore, if you're using an .edmx file, you're not doing "code first".  You're doing either "Database First" or "Model First" (both of which use the .edmx).

In your case, you already have a database, so you're using the "Database First" approach, using EF 4.1 DbContext.  This is not "Code First" (or as you incorrectly stated, Entity First).  This is not a semantic quibble, as "code first" has a very specific meaning.  This is not it.

Now, on to the rest of your question.  Since all your database access has to go through stored procedures, Entity Framework is not a good choice in my opinion.  You would be better off using something like nhibernate, which has much better stored procedure support.

EF is intended to represent your relational data model in objects, and generates all its own sql to access and fill these objects.  If you have to go through the sprocs, EF will be a constant uphill battle for you.

Comment: Couple points.  1) I never said anything about "Code First", someone else mentioned that in their answer.  I specifically said "Entity First" meaning EntityObjects defined by an edmx file, vs "Model First" meaning models defined by code.  If I have the terminology wrong I apologize.   2) With an edmx file I can very simply import a  stored procedure as a function on an EntityObject.  Is there something wrong with this method that I am not aware of?

Comment: @JamesP.Wright - "Model First" has a specific meaning as well, and that is that you define your model in the model designer, then generate your database from the model (as well as entities).  What you are referring to is called "Database First", because the model (in this case, the .edmx file) is generated from your database.  There is nothing called "Entity First".  I'm not sure what you mean by "function on an EntityObject".  Stored Procs can be exected from functions generated from the context, and you can create mappings to objects, but like I said.. this is an uphill battle.

Comment: I'm referring to this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx  This looks pretty simple to me, though I have yet to try it.  I appreciate the terminology explanations as I am still new to this.